# Why is する used with things like 匂い・ネックレス・イヤリング?

Tags: grammar

These don't seem like the standard Noun+する verbs to me (e.g 食事する) and I have noticed that they only seem to take the している・していた forms. Why is this, and if I wished to say "put a necklace on", would I use つける?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11186/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15383/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does する mean when it does not mean "do"? （血のにおいがする）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/what-does-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-mean-when-it-does-not-mean-do-%e8%a1%80%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8a%e3%81%84%e3%81%8c%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

Comment: Also related: [Use of 掛ける vs する for 眼鏡 or サングラス](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56529/use-of-%e6%8e%9b%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b-vs-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-for-%e7%9c%bc%e9%8f%a1-or-%e3%82%b5%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%82%b9/56537#56537)

Answer (score 3):

According to [*A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar*, page 435](https://core6000.neocities.org/dojg/entries/154.html):

> する
>   Something is perceived by someone's non-visual senses.
>   *feel; smell; hear*.
>
> Example sentence[s]:
>   子供達の声がした・しました。
>   I heard children's voices.

Answer (score 2):

> These don't seem like the standard Noun+する verbs to me (e.g 食事する)

する has a lot of meanings and usages, which include におい・味・音・声がする (smell, taste, hear)、感じ・気がする (feel)、眼鏡・ネクタイ・指輪・ネックレス・イヤリングをする (wear/put on). These are not suru-verbs (サ変動詞) and require the particle を or が. (◎食事する, ◎食事をする, ◎眼鏡をする, not 眼鏡する, ◎音がする, not 音する)

> and I have noticed that they only seem to take the している・していた forms. Why is this, and if I wished to say "put a necklace on", would I use つける?

You can use the する・した forms, too. For example:

> 「キッチンからいい**においがする**。」
>   「二階で何か変な**音がした**よ。」
>   「どこかで見たような**気がする**。」
>   「お葬式ではパールの**ネックレスをします**・つけます。」
>   「明日は**ネクタイをして**きてください。」
>   「左手に**包帯をした**人」

With 「眼鏡・ネクタイ・ネックレスetc.をする」, you can usually use する・つける (or かける, [締]{し}める, はめる etc. depending on the item) for the action "to put on", and している, つけている etc. for the state "(is) wear(ing)~~". For example:

> 佐藤さんはいつも指輪をしています。(はめています)
>   赤いネクタイをしている人 (赤いネクタイをした人 is also fine)