# What does emphasis mean in the がして of the following sentence?

Tags: translation, emphasis

I'm translating this old book I have from Japanese to English, and I come across the following sentence.

> 背後で聞き覚えのある声**がして**、思わず一歩後ずさってしまった。

I think in the above instance the して is being used to emphasis, as defined by the [fourth definition](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) on Jisho.org, shown below.

> 1. by (indicating means of action); as (a group, etc.)​
> 2. indicates patient of a causative expression​ - as 〜をして in modern Japanese
> 3. acts as a connective - ​after the ren'youkei form of an adjective
> 4. adds emphasis - ​after an adverb or a particle

What does 'add emphasis' mean, and is my understanding of the use of して in the above sentence correct?

EDIT: Added answer to my question: 「して」じゃなくて「する」を調べたほうがいいですよ。#7 to be sensed (of a smell, noise, etc.)​ – Chocolate

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17850/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62233/9831

Comment: 「して」じゃなくて「[する](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)」を調べたほうがいいですよ。#7 `to be sensed (of a smell, noise, etc.)`​

Comment: @Chocolate　じゃ、　きみは上に「して」をparticleないと思いですか？

Comment: The して in your example is the te-form of the verb する. It's not a particle. The sentence means 背後で、聞き覚えのある声がした。それで、思わず一歩あとずさってしまった。

Comment: もう～、私はばかですよ！私はparticleに至る所を見ている！私は日本語を休みにかもしれませんか。。。。。。